# How to check webrequest connections on iis?

Tags: c#, asp.net, httpwebrequest

Im having a problem with a webrequest on my site. I think the problem is that i dont close the response. Is there a way to check how many open connentions i have at a given time with the server I am trying to reach.

Comment: if you dont close your webrequest for a while, will it not give up with a timeout ?

Comment: Q: What exactly are the symptoms of this "problem"?  Perhaps you're correct about "open connections" ... or perhaps you're on completely the wrong track.  What's the actual problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: @ChandraSekharWalajapet  Im doing a webrequest to get xml data from an exteral source. The service is very unstable and gives a Timeout Exception. When i restart my IIS  server the problem dissapears for a while. My theory is that when I don't close my connection I get to many open connections  to the endpoint and therefor the new connections times out.

Comment: @paulsm4 Take a look at my comment above.

Comment: Q: Is your web app running on IIS, invoking an external web service?  Q: Can you check the logs from the remote WS server?  Q: Have you checked both the IIS and Windows event logs on your local, IIS server?  If the local web app is timing out trying to read from the remote WS, then the remote WS is probably the culprit, true?  Can you tell us more about it?

Answer (score 2):

I suggest to use the TCPView from sysinternals

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897437.aspx

[image]